# Hosting more canvas applications on the same website

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I would like to host more applications on the same domain so to have, as canvas URL, subfolders like www.mydomain.com/app1, www.mydomain.com/app2 and so on.

I can't create singular virtual directories since just the root is an IIS virtual directory. So I was thinking to have in each VD just a file to redirect to a page on the root which can work as real entrypoint of the application (i.e. app1_default.aspx, app2_defaul.aspx etc.)

However, it looks as if it doesn't work because the "FacebookConfigurationSection" retrieves both the app ID and the Secret Key from the web.config, which is obviously unique.

Is there any workaround?

thanks

marco

Answer (score 0):

Using the Facebook configuration section is one way of setting your appId/appSecret/etc., but we also support registering your apps in code. I have actually already create a short sample on how to do that [here](https://gist.github.com/820881). Basically, you just implement IFacebookApplication and make your implementation aware of your multiple apps. How you do that is up to you, but it is fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a similar setup, the only way I could do this was to leave the top level website empty (no web.config there to inherit) and then have each app as an application inside that website

You can also get this running on IIS Express by setting a virtual folder that has a folder in the url instead of the standard root that IIS Express use. Then changing the hosting file for IIS Express and making sure it is pointing to an empty folder for the top level website so that the web.config is not inherited.